# How do I convert 2d character rigging animation to frame by frame sprite animation?

Tags: unity, 2d, animation, rigging

In [this video](https://youtu.be/vap04-Py9QM) after about the 8th minute, he says he converted them from character rigged animation to the frame by frame animation, so I searched but couldn't find any answers on google. How do I convert rigged 2d animations to frame-by-frame animations?

Comment: I would be surprised if a lot of the popular skeletal animation programs (like Spriter, Spine, etc.) don't have that export option.

Answer (score 2):

There are no built-in tools to do that I'm afraid. I've made [this simple tool](https://github.com/MarekMarchlewicz/Animation2Flipbook) to do this kind of export automatically.

Hope you'll find it helpful!

Comment: The link you posted generates a 404 error. Maybe that repository is currently private?

Comment: You should be able to access it now @liggiorgio

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to be sure, but he likely used a 3rd party tool like Esoteric Software's Spine to create both the bone and frame-by-frame animation for the dog.

There are no built in tools or features in Unity to render 2D bone based animations as individual sprites at the moment.